# Check if bone is manipulated by constraints

Tags: python, bones, constraints

My question is following.
Is it possible to see if a pose bone is manipulated/influenced by any constraint.

Python offers the function in_ik_chain for bones. Is something similar possible for other constraints? If so, how? :-)

And as small addition. Is it also possible to get the bone that is used as target?

Comment: Are you looking for a Python-based way of seeing influences, or just through the GUI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All constraints on the active pose bone,

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
pbone = context.active_pose_bone

for con in pbone.constraints:
    print("Constraint:", con.type)
    target = getattr(con, "target", None)
    if target:
        print("Target:", target.name, con.subtarget)
    print()
```

Other ways to access pose bones of an armature object

```
# armature object has the pose.bones collection
arm_obj = bpy.data.objects.get("Armature")
if arm_obj:
    #bone named "Bone"
    pbone = arm_obj.pose.bones.get("Bone")
    #items() gives key value pairs
    for name, pbone in arm_obj.pose.bones.items():
        print(name, pbone)
```